# Armature severely deformed mesh

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I've looked around on this forum and have not really found a solution to my particular issue. I have created a lego character and am trying to rig it. It has all worked except for the leg, which as you can see is blocky where I want it to be smooth.

[image]

I tried corrective smoothing, however it yields the following artifact. Any help or pointers to similar threads would be appreciated.

[image]

Also, here is a wireframe of the legs if necessary.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue. If anyone is having similar issues, you may have some topology that does not fit well with the bones. The solution that I found was to re-weight the armature and remove the corrective smoothing modifier from the entire mesh. I've found that for a mesh where the goal is to create a soft-bendy sort of pose, it's best to only use the corrective smoothing on specific vertex groups rather than the entire mesh.

Comment: If you want a soft bending deformation, consider using a lattice or mesh deform modifier. You can use bendy bones to control the lattice/ mesh deform object, and use vertex groups to define which areas the lattice/mesh deformer affect. Mesh deformers support corrective smooth modifier.

Also, it might help to add a few loops. Unless you're using a toaster, you don't need to keep it lo-poly. Loops will help keep it smooth. Corrective smooth probably gave you glitches because it didn't have much geometry to work with.